# Using Fiddler's to send request to a ASP.NET server with additional node not defined in DataContract, and expecting it to throw an exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, fiddler, datacontractserializer

Fiddler is showing any exception from the server when there is an additional node in the xml which is not defined in the DataContract.

I am executing a PUT through fiddler. I am passing an additional node in my xml, i.e a DataMember is not defined in c# object, but after executing this i am not getting any exception.

Following is the request header and body for it, in the below example  in Task is never defined but provided in the xml.

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-length: 1306
Content-Type: application/xml
Authorization: admin:admin
Host: ***
```

**Request Body**

```
<Task xmlns="http://****" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <FirstName>abc</FirstName>
    <xyz>test</xyz>
</Task>
```

**C# Object**

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://***")]
public class Task
{
        [DataMember]
        public string FirstName{ get; set; }
}
```

With the above scenario why doesn't the server throw any exception?

Comment: Why do you expect it to return HTTP 400? That error code is for malformed HTTP requests, and your request is perfectly valid. Even the XML payload is valid, it only doesn't match your web service.

Comment: I think i framed my question wrong, as you both have mentioned I was expecting the server to throw some exception when reading the input and found the extra field <xyz>. @CodingWithSpike I will look into DataContractSerializer.

Comment: This article talks about DataContractSerializer ignoring the additional fileds. Thanks @CodingWithSpike http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731138(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @EricLaw - Moved my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be your web server that you would expect to return an error code, not fiddler. It has been a couple years since I did WCF, but if I remember correctly, your additional `xyz` field in the request will just be ignored by the `DataContractSerializer`.